# How to convert a multidimensional array of strings to floats with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am returning a large JSON object, and every element within a specific section is a string. I need to be able to convert all of these to floats.

**How the array currently is:**

```
[
    ["1402408800","0.0"],
    ["1402408800","0.0"],
    ["1402408800","0.0"],
]
```

**How it needs to be after conversion:**

```
[
    [1402408800,0.0],
    [1402408800,0.0],
    [1402408800,0.0],
]
```

I am able to reference this array with `v.PriceHistory`, so I attempted the following:

```
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < v.PriceHistory.length; i++) {
    parseFloat(v.PriceHistory[i]);
    newArr += v.PriceHistory[i];
}
```

Although, the above just returns it all as a single array, and not back into its original format.

Tried a few things and looked online, but there were none about converting a multidimensional array.

Comment: I've added another generic solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery, you can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to change all elements in an array:

```
var a = [
    ["1402408800","0.0"],
    ["1402408800","0.0"],
    ["1402408800","0.0"],
];

a = a.map(function(elem) {
    return elem.map(function(elem2) {
        return parseFloat(elem2);
    });
});
```

---

Here is a totally generic function that works for any n-dimensional array:

```
(function(elem) {
   var callee = arguments.callee;
   return elem instanceof Array ? elem.map(function(elem2) { return callee(elem2); })
                                : parseFloat(elem);
 })
(["1", "2", ["10", "20", ["100", "200"], "30"]]);
```

If you copy and paste to console, you will see the output:

```
[1, 2, [10, 20, [100, 200], 30]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the large object (the first code segment in your post) and set the second element of the current array to the parsed value.

Code sample (where `l` is the large object):

```
for (var i = 0; i < l.length; ++i) {
    l[i][1] = parseFloat(l[i][1]);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ogcy4t3x/)

Comment: Little vague. Could you provide a sample of what you are trying to explain?

Comment: I am replacing the string value inside the array (the array you show in the first code segment of your post) with the value that is obtained after calling `parseFloat` on the string value. (also added a fiddle for you)

Comment: Works, slightly. Still leaves the 0 index as a string. Check the console: `0:"1402408800", 1: 0`

Comment: @fizzix Sorry, didn't realize the first was also a string. Just duplicate the line in the for loop and replace the 1 with a 0 in the second instance.

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to go through each elements of your array, check this it will help you

```
var yourArray = /*YOUR ARRAY*/;
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
    var currentArray = yourArray[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < currentArray.length; j++) {
        if(!newArray[i]){
           newArray[i]=[];
        }
        newArray[i][j] = parseFloat(currentArray[j], 10);
    }
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Getting an error of: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`. Happens at `newArray[i][j] = parseFloat(yourArray[i][j], 10);`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < v.PriceHistory.length; i++) {
  newArr[i] = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < v.PriceHistory[i].length; k++) {
  newArr[i].push(parseFloat(Price[i][k]));
  }
}
```

does this work?